# Как посчитать возраст из даты DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: reactjs

Как мне посчитать возраст подскажите пожалуйста
в конст вносится значения такого вида **DD.MM.YYYY**

```
const [vozrast12, setVozrast12] = useState('15.12.1998')
```

как мне высчитать возраст на текущую дату с `new Date` что то не получается выводит **NaN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Считаем разницу лет**

Разбиваем строку по '.' и преобразуем значение в число
Создаем дату "пользователя"
Получаем текущую дату
Высчитываем год и месяц, который прошел и возвращаем.

```js
const strDate = '15.12.1998';

function getAge(str) {
  const dd = str.split('.').map(d => Number(d));
  const ageEnter = new Date(dd[2], dd[1] - 1, dd[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
  const dateNow = new Date();
  const age = dateNow.getFullYear() - ageEnter.getFullYear();
  const month = dateNow.getMonth() - ageEnter.getMonth();
  return `Возраст ${age} лет и ${month} месяцев`
}

console.log(getAge(strDate));
```

Comment: Ты лучший просто, спасибо!))