# Подскажите пожалуйста как посчитать сколько прошло времени с определенной даты JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, дата

Подскажите пожалуйста как посчитать сколько прошло времени(месяцев, дней, часов, минут, секунд) с 06.09.2022

Comment: [Данный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-dd-mm-yyyy/1474591#1474591) похож на то что вам нужно?

Comment: не совсем подходит

Comment: Ну так там все есть ) Осталось по примеру только высчитать дни, минуты, и т.д.