# проверить что дата минимум 18 лет и максимум 100 лет?

Tags: javascript, дата

подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить проверку что введенная дата в формате dd.mm.yyyy входит в промежуток 18-100 лет или подскажите методы в date-fns

Comment: Дату и протяженность интервала сравнивать нельзя. В условии чего-то не хватает

Comment: @MBo перефразирую, введенная дата старше 18 лет (от текущей даты) и меньше 100 лет от текущей даты.

Comment: ОК, отредактируйте вопрос примерно так  - разница между введенной датой и текущей составляет от 18 до 100 лет (думаю, речь идёт о возрасте человека).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как посчитать возраст из даты DD.MM.YYYY](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474583/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно узнать разность между двумя датами, в миллисекундах. После переводим в года, и сравниваем.

```
var diff = Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

Comment: А как вы проверяете, то что дата в формате `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Comment: Преобразую в строку и сравню каждый показатель с константами (1 < dd < 31; 1 < mm < 12; 1 < yyyy < 2023). Ну или воспользуюсь отловом ошибок.

Comment: А если дата будет такая: `12.12.2023`? Как вы поймёте, где день, а где месяц?

Comment: Из разницы в миллисекундах нельзя точно узнать разницу в годах, последняя зависит от конкретных дат

Comment: @ΝNL993 так формат определённый? Система всегда их читает как dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: @MrSvinia при попытке преобразовать в строку, у меня получается 2/8/2023, до сих пор так уверены? Код: `let date = new Date(Date.now()); console.log(date.toLocaleDateString()) // 2/8/2023`

Comment: @ΝNL993, Так оно-то сегодняшняя дата... Значит оно снимает как mm.dd.yyyy. Значит весь код перегоняем под съёмную. Не занимаемся мазохизмом. Если руки чешутся - делаем ручками функцию определения деления разрядов и отдельно каждый вычисляем.

Comment: @MrSvinia как раз таки то, что вы хотите сделать - мазохизм. Проблема решается просто, нужно в первый аргумент в методе `toLocaleDateString`, передать строку `'ru'`, чтобы получилось вот так: `let date = new Date(Date.now()); console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ru')) // 08.02.2023`

Comment: @ΝNL993, ну значит и сказке конец, а кто не слушал - программист.